# Maximum Likelyhood Estimator (MLE) vs. Bias

Tags: maximum-likelihood, unbiased-estimator

If we use the MLE methhod to find the estimator of the variance we get:

$\hat\sigma ^2 = \frac{\sum(x_i - \mu)^2}{n}$

Where we can plug the MLE estimator for $\mu$ and get:

$\hat\sigma ^2 = \frac{\sum(x_i - \bar x)^2}{n}$

But we know that this estimator is biased, and in order to correct for the bias, we need to use $n-1$ instead of $n$:

$S ^2 = \frac{\sum(x_i - \bar x)^2}{n - 1}$

My question is why do we care more for bias than for the likelyhood?
Subquestion - how much is the unbiased estimator less likely to appear given an (arbitrary) sample ?

**Update:**

I don't see how this is a duplicate. I understand that this estimator is biased. I completely agree with the answer given in the linked "duplicate". I'm asking something completely different. I'm asking why do we care more about correcting the bias, than we care about maximizing the likelihood.

In the normal example, the MLE estimators are what maximizes the likelihood function of our sample. So say we got $(\hat\mu, \hat\sigma^2) = (100, 25) $ for n of 100. Then correcting the bias will give us $(100, 25*\frac{100}{99} = 25.25)$ which will not maximize the likelihood. i.e. it is not the maximum anymore.

So why do we care about fixing the bias more than maximizing the likelihood? I guess the answer is that the likelihood is less important than the bias, though I wonder - why?

Comment: A simple remark: if $\hat\theta$ is the MLE for $\theta$, $h(\hat\theta)$ is the MLE for $h(\theta)$, while, if $\hat\theta$ is unbiased for $\theta$, $h(\hat\theta)$ is most often biased for $h(\theta)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand the subquestion.

Regarding the question, it is not that we care more for bias that for the likelihood. The ML principle has important advantages. In order to compare estimates, however, we may want to restrict ourselves to a given class: without such restriction, there may be no such thing as a best estimator.

One such class is that of unbiased estimators. It makes sense to correct the bias of the MLE so that we can compare with other unbiased estimators in search, for example, of a minimum variance unbiased estimator.

Comment: I see, this is indeed a good reason, as all the minimum variance theorems require unbiased estimators.

Comment: So to conclude - we rather give up a bit of likelihood, and get in return an estimator which is unbiased and has minimum variance.

Comment: I tried to simulate it now, calculating both the unbiased estimator and the biased estimator for a normal distribution with n=1000, and I did it 100 times and calculated the variance of both estimators - it was consistently bigger for the unbiased estimator. I ran this a few times and always the same result. So how can this be?

Comment: It also makes sense that the unbiased estimator will give bigger variance, as the results spread out more.